# How can I cd to a long path in DOS 6.22?

Tags: ms-dos, directory-listing, cd, working-directory

I have a legacy PC which I have installed DOS 6.22 onto. I'm not sure what specific version this is, but it had CD drivers included, so I'm suspecting it wasn't exactly "bare bones".

I created a CD with some files I want to access from that machine, but some folders unfortunately have more than 8 characters in length. Supposedly using first 6 characters followed by `~1` is supposed to change my directory, but this doesn't want to work. There's no `/X` dir option either. Whatever I've tried, I just got `Invalid directory` back.

When I'm doing the `dir` on the folder, all filenames seem to be truncated to 8 characters with no indication that any of then might be over the limit. `cd` to the short ones works.

What could be at fault here? Is there any way for me to access those files?

Comment: if you just do a `dir` how are the names listed?

Comment: @EBGreen The first 8 characters are shown. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: So if you pick one of those and type `CD FOOBAR01` (assuming FOOBAR01 is one of them) what happens?

Comment: @EBGreen `Invalid directory`.

Comment: To whoever voted this "too broad": I am willing to provide as much specific information about my problem as necessary, I just don't know what could be helpful. This is a physical machine so unfortunately can't readily share it. I could provide the DOS FDD image I used if that would help.

Comment: What do you get from `ver`?

Comment: Ok, I've hacked around a bit and switched to FreeDOS. The utility `SHSUCDX` used by that to replace `MSCDEX` has a very interesting `/~` option to generate tildes (which works). I'll self-answer this once I know enough about the issue.

Comment: In Win 10 CMD, wild cards work; e.g. if in C:\Windows\ then cd sys\* gets to C:\Windoews\System32. Not sure if that worked in DOS.

Answer (score 0):

Do a DIR /ad to confirm the directory is a listing of directories only.  It could be you're trying to change directory into what it thinks is a file.

If they are all indeed directories, you should be able to short-cut the CD command to as many letters as required for it to be unique, followed by an asterisk, i.e.

cd FOOBAR*

It should, at the very least, change into the first matching directory it finds.